# not able to authenticate another user in ldap server

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

below test case i am using to authenticate a user in my ldap directory,I am able to connect to the server and udpate the values.I have set the user password but when i am trying to retrieve it , getting null value.

as we can't retrieve ldap password simply in plain text format, can anyone help me to authenticate it anyway.

```
public void testFastBind() throws NamingException {
    ldapUtils.setBaseDN("ou=testusers,O=userstore,c=corp");
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://10.9.196.21:389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=mru1,OU=ADMIN,O=userstore,C=corp");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "tcs123");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

    // authenticating to the ldap server
    DirContext ctx = ldapUtils.getContext("ldap://10.9.196.21:389", "cn=TAR4ADM,OU=ADMIN,O=userstore,C=corp",
            "ADldsadmin16");

    // domain name to authenticate
    String DN = "cn=mru1,ou=testusers,O=userstore,c=corp";

    // searching for the domain name
    try {
        ctx.lookup(DN);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Attributes attribute = ctx.getAttributes(DN);
    System.out.println("password =" + attribute.get("userPassword")); 
    // password value is null

    boolean flag = true;

    try {
        // to authenticatectx mru1
        DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env); 
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        flag = false;
    }
    System.out.println("connection successful : " + flag);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to retrieve the password?

Comment: i want to authenticate username using it , not getting how to authenticate without retrieving it.

Comment: Use LDAP for the same. You are already doing it, though the user id and password is hardcoded. Same method should be used to authenticate users. if its valid, it will run fine, else it will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks Rishi Goel made some changes and now it is working fine,